# Assigning value to id only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I've a problem that has been bugging me for a while now.

I have 14 divs each which must be assigned a random ID (between 1 and 14) each time the page loads.
Each of these divs have the class ".image-box" and the format of the ID I'm trying to assign is 'box14'

I have the JS code working to assign random IDs but I'm having trouble not getting the same ID to assign twice.

JavaScript

```
var used_id = new Array();

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        assign_id();

        function assign_id()
        {
            $('.image-box').each(function (i, obj) {
                random_number();
                function random_number(){
                number = 2 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 14);
                var box_id = 'box' + number;

                if((box_id.indexOf(used_id) !== -1) === -1)
                    {
                        $(this).attr('id',box_id);
                        used_id.push(box_id);
                    }


                else
                    {
                    random_number();
                    }   
                }
            });

        }

    });
```

Thanks for your help,

Cheers

Comment: Does it have to be random?  Can `assign_id()` assign an incrementing value?

Comment: why you want to assign Id's in that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want and [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/player889/CPc4R/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    assign_id();
});
function assign_id() {
    var numberOfDiv = $('.image-box').length;
    var listOfRandomNumber = myFunction(numberOfDiv);
    $('.image-box').each(function(i, obj) {
        $(this).attr("id",listOfRandomNumber[i]);
    });
};

//Getting List Of Number contains 1 to the number of Div which is 
//14 in this case.
function myFunction(numberOfDiv ) {
    for (var i = 1, ar = []; i < numberOfDiv +1 ; i++) {
        ar[i] = i;
    }
    ar.sort(function() {
        return Math.random() - 0.5;
    });
    return ar;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Mmm, [random...](http://xkcd.com/221/)

Instead of using a randomly generated number (which, as your experiencing, may randomly *repeat* values) just use an incrementally-updated counter when assigning IDs.

```
function assign_id() {
    var counter = 0;
    $('.image-box').each(function (i, obj) {
       $(this).attr('id','image-box-' + counter++); }   
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have a global array like u have for user_id and push assigned div ids into array. Then you can check before assigning random id to div. If it is assigned use different one.

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use incremental values(or something like (new Date).getTime()) if all you want to do is assign unique values. But if, for some reason, you must have randomly-picked values(only from 1-14) then use something like this to pick unique/random values

```
var arrayId = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];

function getRandomId(array) {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (array.length));
    var randomId = array.splice(randomIndex, 1);
    return randomId[0];
}
```

Now `getRandomId(arrayId)` would return a randomly picked value from your array and then remove that value so that it is not repeated.

Answer (score 0):

First how you'd use my implementation:

```
var takeOne = makeDiminishingChoice(14);
```

In this case, `takeOne` is a function that you can call up to 14 times to get a unique random number between 1 and 14.

For example, this will output the numbers between 1 and 14 in random order:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        console.log(takeOne());
}
```

And here is the implementation of `makeDiminishingChoice` itself:

```
var makeDiminishingChoice = function (howMany) {

        // Generate the available choice "space" that we can select a random value from.
        var pickFrom = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
                pickFrom.push(i);
        }

        // Return a function that, when called, will return a value from the search space,
        // until there are no more values left.
        return function() {

                if (pickFrom.length === 0) {
                        throw "You have requested too many values. " + howMany + " values have already been used."
                }

                var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * pickFrom.length);
                return pickFrom.splice(randomIndex, 1)[0];
        };
};
```